# CMD Installation of SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, cmd

I am installing SQL Server 2012 from cmd I pass parameter `SECURITYMODE = SQL` for installing SQL Server on mixed mode instead of Windows Authentication mode but it is installing in windows authentication mode.

Here is my parameters

```
/q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQLEngine /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /UpdateEnabled=False /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=XYZ
```

Comment: Not that it answers the question but why are you trying to install an unsupported version of SQL Server Express?

Comment: I am making and windows application in which on execution of exe here create a local database with tables for that i have to intsall sql server express and i am making exe from advance installer in which in silent install i define these parameters to create database sa is not loging and gives error that it has only windows authentication mode

Comment: But why 2012 and not 2017? SQL Server 2012 is only in extended support now. If you're installing a **free** and new copy of SQL Server, why use something that only with be supported for security updates, when you can use a much more recent version that is fully supported?

Comment: That's not what I asked. SQL Server 2012 is no longer supported. Why don't you install an up-to-date version?

Comment: As for the problem itself, remove `/Q` and check whether there are any error messages. The default  You should also check the [setup logs too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/view-and-read-sql-server-setup-log-files?view=sql-server-2017) to see why SECURITYMODE was ignored.

Comment: You'll find the list of command-line options in [Install SQL Server from the Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-2017). Notice that there's no dropdown option for SQL Server 2012.

Comment: And if you select "older" you get the message "*The requested page is not available for SQL Server previous versions. You have been redirected to the newest product version this page is available for."*